# Cloud Sql Proxy Private IP External application

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

Simple question: Is there any way to connect to a GCP SQL Database under private IP through cloud sql proxy from an external application ? (local development environment)

I followed every step in the official tutorial to configure cloud sql proxy with all requirements, but all connections fail in a sort of timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to connect to a Cloud SQL instance using only private IP through the Cloud SQL proxy will be to install the proxy within [a resource (could be for example a Compute Engine instance) with access to the same VPC network as the Cloud SQL instance](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/private-ip#quick-reference). Since your local development environment might not comply to that requirement the connection will fail.

You could move your local development environment to a compute engine instance located within the same VPC network as your Cloud SQL instance or temporarily enable Public IP on the instance and authorize only your IP through [the authorized network options](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-networks#authorized-networks) and use the Cloud SQL proxy to gain access to the instance.

Comment: Yes, the short answer will be no. The answer is that the proxy should be located within a resource on the same VPC as your instance if you mean to connect to it using only Private IP.

Answer (score 0):

The Cloud SQL proxy will work with a private IP address as long as it can reach the private IP address.

See the "Connecting from an external source" section on the [Configuring Private IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/configure-private-ip#vpn) page for a list of steps to set up a VPN that can provide access to your VPC.